# How can I monitor memory and CPU usage by spark application?

Tags: apache-spark, memory-management, cpu-usage

After running my spark application, I want to monitor its memory and cpu usage to evaluate its performance but couldn't find any option. Is it possible to monitor it?  How can I monitor memory and CPU usage by spark application?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring.html#web-interfaces) can help you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few options:

1. Ganglia is one
2. If you're running on your own cluster, HDP or Cloudera both have real time CPU & memory consumption charts.
3. If you want specific JVM metrics, then I'd recommend [FlameGraph](https://github.com/brendangregg/FlameGraph), though it's not real time.
4. There's also [Grafana](https://grafana.com/), it's extremely powerful, you can track many metrics with it, and it's real time.